# How to enable malicious extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

the apollo-graphql extension was marked as malicious (I'm sure mistakingly) ... I need to enable it to work with it as I really enjoy it.
 How can I force VS Code to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

You can install it again, it was disabled by MS because of the 
[Event-Stream package problem](http://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2018/11/26/event-stream)